# Retrieving Facebook stats from public pages

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to retrieve Facebook statistics—number of likes, number talking about—from public pages that do not require a log in without having the owner of the page authorize my app to get the stats?

I have a web page written with PHP where the owners want to compare themselves to famous people by comparing their likes and number of people talking to those stats on the Facebook pages of famous people. The only information I’ve seen about this suggests that I have to go through a big process to register my PHP script and then have the owners of the famous people’s pages authorize my use of their statistics.

Is this true?

Some pages they compared themselves to so far:

```
https://www.facebook.com/u2
https://www.facebook.com/katyperry
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the OpenGraph version of the URL like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/u2`:

```
{
   "id": "5678046685",
   "name": "U2",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/373668_5678046685_543938367_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/u2",
   "likes": 11405255,
   "category": "Musician/band",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.u2.com http://www.interscope.com/u2 http://www.myspace.com/u2 http://www.imeem.com/u2music",
   "username": "u2",
   "about": "Achtung Baby turned twenty in November with the band  releasing an anniversary edition and a new movie from Davis Guggenheim, From The Sky Down, telling the story...",
   "band_members": "Bono\nThe Edge\nAdam Clayton\nLarry Mullen, Jr.",
   "hometown": "Dublin, Ireland",
   "record_label": "Interscope",
   "talking_about_count": 123045
}
```

And like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/katyperry`

```
{
   "id": "7126051465",
   "name": "Katy Perry",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276633_7126051465_1028240466_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/katyperry",
   "likes": 38667872,
   "category": "Musician/band",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.katyperry.com http://www.myspace.com/katyperry http://www.twitter.com/katyperry",
   "username": "katyperry",
   "about": "Buy 'Teenage Dream' on iTunes & Amazon here: http://goo.gl/oBPoQ ",
   "genre": "Pop-Rock",
   "band_members": "Katy Perry",
   "hometown": "Los Angeles, CA",
   "record_label": "Capitol Records",
   "bio": "When Katy Perry was a fourth grader, her teacher asked the class to make a \u201cvision board\u201d \u2014 a collage of images cut out from magazines that represents the dreams and aspirations you hope to manifest in life. The year was 1993 and Selena had just won a Grammy Award, so nine-year-old Katy chose a photo of the young Latin pop singer holding her golden statuette. Fifteen years later, Perry has been nominated for her first Grammy Award in the \u201cBest Female Pop Vocal Performance\u201d category for her ubiquitous No. 1 single, \"I Kissed a Girl,\" from her platinum Top 10 album One of the Boys, and has been chosen as this year\u2019s My GRAMMY\u00ae Moment artist.  Current sales check in at over 2 million albums and more than 13 million tracks, singles and mobile product globally.\n\n\u201cI found my vision board when I moved apartments recently,\u201d says Perry, now 24. \u201cI knew where I wanted to be even as a young kid. I just didn\u2019t know that if I put one foot in front of the other, I would actually get there someday.\u201d \n\nPerry\u2019s willful determination, not to mention her songwriting and vocal talent and larger-than-life charisma, have led to an astonishing year for the saucer-eyed, raven-haired pop starlet, who, with her cheeky sense of humor and sexy pin-up girl style, was \u201cthe breakthrough star of 2008\u201d as Blender magazine put it in the issue that featured Perry on the cover. \n\nYou could say it all started in April 2008 when Madonna told Ryan Seacrest that Perry\u2019s \u201cUr So Gay\u201d (off her November 2007 EP of the same name) \u2014 a withering kiss-off to a metrosexual ex \u2014 was her favorite song. \u201cIt may have been a small comment on her behalf, but it was a large comment in my world,\u201d Perry recalls. \u201cIt was like a big boat leaving the dock and getting a champagne send-off.\u201d Shortly after being anointed by the Queen of Pop, Perry released her debut single \u201cI Kissed A Girl\u201d \u2014 a provocative ode to the beauty of women that ruled radio over the summer of 2008, becoming an all-format hit and shooting to No. 1 on the Billboard Hot 100 where it stayed put for seven straight weeks and tied The Beatles\u2019 Capitol Records record for weeks at No. 1. The video was nominated for five MTV Video Music Awards, including a nod for Perry for \u201cBest New Artist\u201d and became the No. 1 most viewed music video of 2008 on MySpace. A No. 1 airplay smash in 22 countries and the 2009 People\u2019s Choice award winner for \u201cFavorite Pop Song,\u201d \u201cI Kissed A Girl\u201d has sold more than six million tracks worldwide. Its popularity also made Perry a ripe target for Fox News commentator Bill O\u2019Reilly, who convened a panel of hand-wringing analysts to discuss the effect of the song on America\u2019s impressionable youth. Perry was also voted \u201cBest New Artist\u201d by readers of Rolling Stone and PerezHilton.com\n\nOn June 17, 2008, EMI Music released One of the Boys, a witty romp through Perry\u2019s brightly colored world that showcases her sharp, candid lyrics, big voice, and feisty, girl-power swagger, as well as her appealing vulnerability on songs like her latest single, \u201cThinking Of You.\u201d \u201cI think people can appreciate a songwriter who shows different sides,\u201d she says. \u201cThe whole angst thing is cool, but if that\u2019s all you\u2019ve got, it's just boring. Everything I write, whether it\u2019s happy or sad, has a sense of humor to it.\u201d Case in point: the album\u2019s spunky, high-voltage second single \u201cHot N Cold,\u201d which became Perry\u2019s second No. 1 single and international hit, selling nearly three million digital tracks since its release. The eye-popping video, with its hilarious wedding theme, became the No. 2 most-viewed premiere of all time on MySpace, proving to armchair critics and naysayers that the success of this irrepressible young woman in the satin onesie and fishnets was no fluke. When Saturday Night Live spoofed her, it was official: Katy Perry was a bonafide cultural phenomenon. \n\nSo why does Perry think that she\u2019s connected with a mass audience when the road to stardom is littered with the failed dreams of aspiring wannabes? \u201cBecause I\u2019m just myself,\u201d she says, \u201cand that\u2019s all people want. People want to hear artists who are themselves, but who do interesting things and sing about them in an interesting way that maybe they have tried to conceive but couldn\u2019t. I get a lot of girls who come up to me and say, \u2018When I heard \u2018Thinking of You,\u2019 I felt that way to a T, but I never knew anyone who could put my feelings into words.\u2019 I think that\u2019s why people find me relatable. Plus, anybody can meet me. I\u2019m not distant. I\u2019m very much the same person I was before the hit singles. I just have a schedule for breakfast, lunch, and dinner.\u201d\n\nFans do seem to respond to Perry\u2019s approachable girl-next-door quality (if the girl next door were a self-described \u201cglamour ninja\u201d), perhaps because it\u2019s not an act. The middle child of two pastors, Perry grew up singing in church. \u201cMy dad would give me ten dollars, which is a lot of money when you\u2019re nine, to sing at church, on tables at restaurants, at family functions, just about anywhere,\u201d she says. Perry was raised on a strict diet of church music; \u201csecular music,\u201d as her mother called it, was \u201cnot allowed.\u201d But one night during a slumber party, Perry happened upon a Queen record \u201cand the heavens opened and saved me,\u201d she says. \u201cFrom then on, they have been my biggest influence. Their musicality and lyrics were so flamboyant and real. I\u2019d never heard anything like it.\u201d\n\nBy the time she was 15, Perry was determined to pursue a path in music. She spent some time in Nashville working with professional songwriters \u2014 \u201cthese seasoned country music vets who had been writing songs for forever\u201d \u2014 and honing her own songwriting skills. \u201cEvery single one of my songs is drawn 100 percent directly from my life.\u201d At 17, Perry met legendary producer and songwriter Glen Ballard, who spent years guiding and developing her talent and songwriting. The strength of the songs and Perry\u2019s full-throated voice captured the attention of Capitol Music Group, which signed her in Spring 2007. \u201cI\u2019ve been through a lot of highs and a lot of lows in this business,\u201d Perry says. \u201cBefore I got signed, it was tough. I\u2019d write a check for my rent and next to it, I\u2019d write, \u2018Please, God, please.\u2019 But I didn\u2019t jump off the Hollywood sign. Everything always works out for the best.\u201d\n\nIt\u2019s a long way from being broke to stealing the show at the MTV Latin America \u201cLos Premios Awards\u201d (where Perry face-planted into a large pink cake) and hosting and performing at the MTV Europe Music Awards in Liverpool, England, which she did in November 2008, picking up the award for \u201cBest New Act\u201d in the process. Now Perry is gearing up for her first-ever international headlining tour, something she\u2019s ready to tackle after spending a grueling summer on the Vans Warped Tour \u2014 a multi-band circus that one critic likened \u201cthe running of the bulls in Pamplona...minus the bulls, or the quaint Basque scenery.\u201d \u201cWarped was the hardest thing I\u2019ve ever done,\u201d Perry admits. \u201cIt was like being in the army, like GI Jane getting my ass kicked every single day, but now I know how to deal with any situation.\u201d\n",
   "can_post": true,
   "talking_about_count": 638804
}
```